# Install symfony 6 in windows 10

Tags: php, symfony6

I am trying to download and install symfony6, But by default it is downloading the symfony5. Can some one people help me the right process to download the symfony6 .exe file and install it to Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you can go to the [github repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/6.0) and find it there if you have problems with the download, could also run the composer command `composer require symfony/symfony`, should be v 6.0.2. And if that doesn't work with composer you can specify the version `composer require symfony/symfony:6.0.2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding me, I went to symfony github. But no where they written this command. Could you please share the exact link from where you see this command composer require symfony/symfony

Comment: This is the composer [symfony package page](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony), also in the symfony [setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) documentation you can see how to use composer.

Comment: and, I run the  composer require symfony/symfony, but it is just creating the vendor folder but not installing symfony to windows 10

Comment: hhmm, well I would try to contact thier support for more information, maybe they only provide v5 for now, maybe v6 is not stable yet, I have no idea, But woth a try. Hopefully someone with better exp about this could help you out more =]

Comment: no, they write in the website they were supporting for version6 as well But not working

Comment: How did you install Symfony? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to setup a symofony project using *composer*.
Try to use one of this commands:

- `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_directory`
- `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_directory`

detailed guide is here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

It will create project directory with neccessery subdirectories and files.
Also, you can specify particular symfony version, for example:

`composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"^5.4" my_project_directory`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Which parts ensure that Symfony v6 is installed instead of v5?

Comment: Thanks for response.Symfony CLI version v4.27.4 (c) 2017-2022 Symfony SAS
. I try to download the .exe file from symfony website but it is not downloading the latest version 6 for windows 10.  (Installation .exe file-> double click->next..-> finish)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem was solved after I updated my composer version to the latest version of 2.3.4. Check if your composer is not up to the latest version. It could be the reason. Go to the composer website ( https://getcomposer.org/download/ ) and download Composer-Setup.exe once you run that it will run the installation and update to the latest version. You may also need to restart your PC if the new version does show up when you type the composer -v in your terminal.